# How to have 2 adjacents blocks without display:inline-block?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have been spending hours on that...with no success.

Since inline-block is not well-supported by IE6&7, I wanted to know if it is possible to have the same render using other attributes given by the following code :

```
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
.img {
float: left;
width:17px;
height:15px;
display:block;
background-color: #FD3;
border-style:solid;
}
.txt {
float: left;
}
.parent {
display: inline-block
}
</style></head><body>
Follow Me
<div class="parent ">
<div class="img"></div>
<div class="img"></div>
<div class="txt">(a comment)</div>
</div></body></html>
```

Careful : I cannot add/change the container of "Follow me" (using for instance a `float:left`).  I can control ONLY what is inside the div "parent" (and the div "parent" itself)

Do you have a workaround?

Thx

Comment: And what do you want to achieve? Please make this more clean in your question.

Comment: Well I cannot upload an image for giving you the result I want.
But you can copy the code and paste it here http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_display

You will see the visual layout I want (i.e. 2 adjacent images following the text "Follow Me")

Answer (score 1):

Actually, inline-block works in IE6 and IE7, just in a strange way.

Basically, IE6 and IE7 implement inline wrong.  When a naturally inline element has layout (google for "hasLayout" for more info on that) it will act like an inline-block element and respect width/height set on it.

So swap out those <div class=image>s with <span>s so they're naturally inline, and then all you have to do is trigger hasLayout on them and you're good to go.  My typical method is to set a "zoom:1" property on the elements - it's an IE-only properly that won't do anything, but will trigger hasLayout.

An even better solution, of course, is to just use <img> elements, if that's possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 17px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #FD3;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
}
.leftimg {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.rightimg {
    top: 0;
    left: 23px;
}
.txt {
    display: inline;
}
.parent {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 0 46px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
Follow Me
<div class="parent ">
    <div class="img leftimg"></div>
    <div class="img rightimg"></div>
    <div class="txt">(a comment)</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not have IE to test, but anyway, don't forget the doctype, IE behaves differently without it.

Comment: Well it basically works...but this is not I wanted.
In my application, I have many <img> elements !! So I don't want to define a new class with an absolute position for each <img>. That's why there is a <code>float: left;</code>

Answer (score 0):

it's lame, but this works in Chrome 3.0, Firefox 3.5, IE 6, 7 and 8

```
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
  .img {
    display: inline-block;
    width:17px;
    height:15px;
    background-color: #FD3;
    border-style:solid;
  }

  .parent, .txt {
    display: inline;
  }
</style>

<!--[if lte IE 7]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .img {
      display: inline;
    }

    .parent, .txt {
      display: inline;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .img {
      display: inline;
    }
  </style>
![endif]-->

</head><body>
Follow Me
<div class="parent ">
<div class="img"></div>
<div class="img"></div>
<div class="txt">(a comment)</div>
</div></body></html>
```

Comment: Using your code, I don't have the same visual effect in IE8 and FF3...You can try here: http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_display